# jquery-confirm $.confirm triggers multiple modals at single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-confirm

I'm using [jquery-confirm](https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm) plugin and Bootstrap 3. The confirmation works fine but if I open any bootstrap modal on the page before clicking the confirmation button, two confirmation box pop up. If I open bootstrap modal 5 times before clicking the confirmation button, It triggers five confirmation box at the same time overlaying one after another. Why this happening?

Here is my js:

```js
      $('body').on('click', '.confirm', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var form = this.closest("form");

     $.confirm({
         title: "confirmation",
         content: "Are you sure?",
         buttons: {
           'confirm': {
               text: 'proceed',
               keys: ['enter'],
               btnClass: 'btn-red',
               action: function () {
                 form.submit();
               }
           },
           'cancel': {
               text: 'cancel',
               action: function () {
                 return false;
               }
           },
         }
     });
   });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: no one can guess the problem unless you replicate your problem here in the snippet or at least provide all dependencies like the HTML you are working on with this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my code. There was a point where the confirmation reinitialize every time when loading a modal. That makes it trigger multiple times for a single button. Move the initialization code to another place solved the issue. Thank you guys.